# Reference request: relationship between discriminant and smoothness of a conic over arbitrary fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-forms

I'm looking for an (ideally modern) reference of the relationship between the discriminant and smoothness of projective conics over arbitrary fields (including those of characteristic 2). Let $k$ be a field. Let $q(x,y,z)$ be the polynomial
$$q(x,y,z) = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + dxy + exz + fyz\in k(a,b,c,d,e,f)[x,y,z]$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are independent transcendentals over $k$. Then $b(v,w) := q(v+w) - q(v) - q(w)$ defines a bilinear form on $k(a,b,c,d,e,f)^3$. Let $M_b$ be the associated Gram matrix, then $\det(M_b)$ is divisible by 2 as an element of $\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d,e,f]$, and hence we may define:
$$d_q := \frac{1}{2}\det(M_b)\in\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d,e,f]$$

Now let
$$Q(x,y,z) = Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy + Exz + Fyz\in k[x,y,z]$$
then define $D_Q := d_q(A,B,C,D,E,F)$ viewed as an element of $k/k^2$.

Let $\overline{k}$ be an algebraic closure of $k$. I believe the following statement is true:

*For any field $k$, the subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^2_{\overline{k}}$ given by $Q(x,y,z)$ is integral (reduced and irreducible) if and only if $D_Q\ne 0$.*

Does anyone know of a reference (ideally modern and in english) for this? (assuming it's true).

Comment: Unfortunately (?) in french, but definitely modern: *Résultant, discriminant* by
Michel Demazure. L'enseignement mathématique **58**, Issue 3/4, 2012, pp. 333–373

Answer (score 3):

abx's comment gives a French reference "Résultant, discriminant" by Michel Demazure.

Here's a rough digest of the relevant parts:

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field. Let $f\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d\ge 2$. Demazure describes the discriminant $\text{disc}(f)$ of $f$, which is itself a polynomial in the coefficients of $f$, hence an element of $k$, such that $\text{disc}(f) = 0$ if and only if the hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}_k^{n-1}$ defined by $f$ is smooth.

For smoothness, he uses the Jacobian criterion, which amounts to saying that the only common zero (in an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$) of the polynomials $f,D_1f,\ldots,D_nf$ is the origin $(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = (0,\ldots,0)$, where $D_i := \frac{\partial}{\partial X_i}$.

He characterizes this "nonexistence of nontrivial zeroes" in terms of the *resultant* of the family $(D_1f,\ldots,D_nf)$. First, let
$$a(n,d) := \frac{(d-1)^n - (-1)^n}{d}\qquad (\text{Demazure, p360, discussion after Lemme 9})$$

Then the universal discriminant $\text{disc}$ (for homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$) is defined by the rule
$$d^{a(n,d)}\text{disc} = \text{res}(D_1P_{n,d},\ldots,D_nP_{n,d})\qquad(\text{Demazure, Definition 4, p362})$$
where $\text{res}$ is the resultant (see below), and $P_{n,d}$ is the ``universal homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ in $n$ variables'' (e.g., $P_{3,2}$ is just $q(x,y,z)$ in the OP). Precisely, $P_{n,d} = \sum_{\alpha} T_\alpha X^\alpha$ where the sum ranges over all $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^n$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i = d$, $X^\alpha = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{\alpha_i}$, and the $T_\alpha$'s are independent transcendentals.

The resultant is somewhat complicated in general, but if $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ is a family of linear polynomials in $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, where $g_i = \sum_{j = 1}^n g_{ij}X^j$, then the resultant is just
$$\text{res}(g_1,\ldots,g_n) = \det(g_{ij})\qquad\text{(Demazure, Exemple 1, p349)}$$

Thus, the universal discriminant for homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $k$ in the variables $T_\alpha$, and given a homogeneous degree $d$ polynomial $f = \sum_{\alpha}c_\alpha X^\alpha$, its discriminant is

$$\text{disc}(f) = \text{disc}(\{c_\alpha\})\qquad(\text{Demazure, Definition 4, p362, see $\S1$ for notation.})$$
(ie, this is the element of $k$ obtained by replacing the $T_\alpha$'s in the universal discriminant with the actual coefficients $c_\alpha$ of $f$).

Finally, he shows that this discriminant vanishes if and only if $f$ and its $n$ partial derivatives have no nontrivial zero in any field extension (Proposition 12), which is equivalent to the smoothness of the associated hypersurface by taking affine charts and applying the [jacobian criterion for smoothness](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V9) (also see p335 in the introduction).

In the case $(n,d) = (3,2)$ (ternary quadratic forms), we find $a(3,2) = 1$, and hence $\text{disc}(f)$ is precisely as given in the OP.